# asyncio logging for cluster app

Tags: python-3.x, logging, cluster-computing

Need advice on the organization of logging in a clustered application written in Python(asyncio). Applications use the logging module and store logs local file.

See the logs with 3 servers uncomfortable.
I would like to use rsyslog, but there are fears that it will block the application. Another way to use aioredis(push to channel) and another application to collect data in a single file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to ask for `logging` to log on syslog (typically `/dev/log`, which won't block your application), locally (so your application is not bound to your logging system: it's still portable), then let `rsyslog` (I prefer `syslogng` personally) transmit them to a main log server.

Another solution is to use a tool like `logstash` to push your logs to an `elasticsearch` server / cluster so you can browse and graph them easily. In this case, if your log lines are json objects, it's a big win because elasticsearch-side (typically via `kibana`), you'll be able to query, filter, and aggregate on fields of your json documents. Typically graphing info vs warnings vs errors, frequency of errors per file, or per user, etc...